# ngx-cookie-service does not send Cookies in Angular/Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-cookie-service

Angular 16

Ionic 7

ngx-cookie-service 16

With `this.cookieService.set('sessionkey', 'a-unique-hash', null, null, null, false, 'Lax');` or `this.cookieService.set('sessionkey', 'a-unique-hash');` i set a cookie. In my browser tools can i see the cookie for the domain.
But no cookie is send with request to the server.

I expect that the cookies can be seen in the browser tools under "Network" in the **request** (cookies send with the request).

[edit]

All requests has `withCredentials: true`:

```
req = req.clone({
  url: this.apiBaseUrl + req.url,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

[edit]

If I don't clone the request with an object as a parameter, the url is wrong but the cookies are sent.

...the clone() function make the shit. Why?

Comment: you need to sent the header = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, this.cookieService.get()) });

Comment: This sets a header variable and not a cookie within the cookies in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Only Google Chrome does not send the cookies. I tested it several times.

Google Chrome Version 114.0.5735.106 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

With Firefox, the cookies are sent without any problems.

...both on Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - 5.19.0-43-generic.

[edit]

Google Chrome now in Version 114.0.5735.198 and the problem is still there. In Firefox is all OK.

[edit]
It also doesn't work in the current Opera (100.0.4815.21) browser.

Comment: you should rather update the question with the information, than writing it as a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).